# What is the function of Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandPool and how to use it properly?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, codepools

I installed a custom extension for my Magento 2.3 payment gateway, then i want to process the order payment in another extension, then i come across this code within the extension:

```
   <virtualType name="VendorModuleGatewayCommandPool" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Command\CommandPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="capture" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleCaptureCommand</item>
            <item name="settlement" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleSettleCommand</item>
            <item name="sale" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleSettleCommand</item>
            <item name="void" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleVoidCommand</item>
            <item name="retrieve_status" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Gateway\Command\RetrieveStatus</item>
            <item name="cancel" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleCancelCommand</item>
            <item name="refund_later" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleRefundCommand</item>
            <item name="refund" xsi:type="string">VendorModuleRefundCommand</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
  </virtualType>
```

I'm a little bit confused when I analyzed the above code in `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` , is it correct the above code related to `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment`, because when I ran `$payment->void()` it triggers the extension void function somewhere in the code, but when I called `$payment->retrieve_status()` it said undefined function. Is my understanding for this code correct? or perhaps i missed something?